# $S/I$-freeness of $I/I^2$ vs $I/I^{(2)}$, where $I$ is a radical ideal of regular local ring $S$

Tags: ac.commutative-algebra, homological-algebra, prime-ideals, regular-rings

Let $I$ be a radical ideal of a regular local ring $S$. Put $R:=S/I$. Let $I^{(n)}$ be the $n$-th [symbolic power](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symbolic_power_of_an_ideal) of $I$. It is well-known that $I^n \subseteq I^{(n)}$.

Is it true that $I/I^2$ is $R$-free if and only if $I/I^{(2)}$ is $R$-free?

Answer (score 1):

In your case, when $I$ is reduced, one can show that $I/I^2$ is free implies $I$ is a complete intersection and then $I^2=I^{(2)}$.

For this, let height of $I$ be $r$. Let $P$ be  a minimal prime of height $r$ of $I$. Since $I$ is reduced, we get $I_P=P_P$ and since $R_P$ is a regular local ring of dimension $r$, we get that $I/I^2$ must be a free module of rank $r$. So, $I$ is generated by $r$ elements and thus it is a complete intersection.

I do not know whether the converse is true.

Comment: @uno For the converse statement of what Mohan wrote, the Main Theorem of the paper titled *A Variation on a Theme of Vasconcelos* by Daniel A. Smith (Journal of Algebra, 225, 381–390 (2000)) may be of interest.